# How do I open rust doc on a virtual machine

Tags: rust, vmware, vscode-remote, rustdoc

using vscode to ssh archlinux on vmware station pro.
How to open the rust-doc in local browser?

after`cargo doc --open`
WINDOWS reminded me that I needed to use the new app to open this vscode-remote link.but I don't know how to operate

Comment: Not addressing , but you could open `target/doc/<crate name>/index.html` manually after running `cargo doc`.

Comment: ^ That's what I do because I usually have 3 Firefox sessions and a Chromium session open at any given moment, and it's inevitable that any link I click/open outside of one of the browser sessions will open in a different session than I intend.

Comment: got it. Should i install Live Server in vscode?